# mask/change url using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already search regarding this but the result is not what I want. I hope someone can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

I would like to change/mask url using .htaccess from

```
http://localhost/ecwp/eccube/html/wpss/forum
```

to

```
http://localhost/ecwp/eccube/html/forum
```

This is my folder directory(i'm using XAMPP):-

- htdocs

  - ecwp

    - eccube

      - html

        - wpss->forum under this wp themes
        - .htaccess
      - data

For wpss, I'm using wordpress with permalink setting :

```
http://localhost/ecwp/eccube/html/wpss/archives/123
```

Here is .htaccess code:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum/ http://localhost/ecwp/eccube/html/wpss/forum [L]
```

When running this code,

```
http://localhost/ecwp/eccube/html/forum
```

will redirect go to

```
http://localhost/ecwp/eccube/html/wpss/forum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum(.*)$ http://localhost/ecwp/eccube/html/wpss/forum/$1 [L]
```